# Autocomplete R in Sublime Text 2

Tags: r, autocomplete, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I am trying to find a package that would support Autocomplete of the R Syntax in Sublime Text 2 similar to the way Sublime supports for Python or Ruby. That is when start typing 'vec..." it prompts with "vector" in the pop up.

Answer (score 7):

Yep, it exists.

Drag [R.sublime-completions](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2223411/R.sublime-completions) into your `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/R` (or the equivalent folder in Windows). Another way to get to the folder is click Sublime Text > Preferences > Browse Packages...

Also, if you are going to use Sublime Text 2 for R, here is a (shameless) plug for [rtools](https://github.com/karthikram/rtools), which allows you to send selections from ST2 to R. You can install via Package Control.

Comment: wow... you just made my day.   However, I think the file should probably go in `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/` , no?

Comment: The dropbox link is no longer functional. Kindly update.